# nodejs child_process spawn silently fails on windows

Tags: node.js

I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar problem with nodejs child_process spawn on windows.

I can no longer execute a nodejs script that calls child_proces.spawn. (This was working fine until yesterday, when suddenly node stopped working properly. No new software installed or anything that I am aware of that could have triggered this.) The call to spawn simply exits the process and fails with no error code, no error message, just exits silently.

My testcase script looks like this:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

console.log('test 1');
try {
  spawn('c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', ['/d', '/c', 'dir'], { stdio: 'inherit' });
  console.log('test 2');
} catch (err) {
  console.log('err', err);
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
PS C:\test> node .\index.js
test 1
PS C:\test>
```

Running nodejs v14.17.1 on Windows 10. (I've also tried with nodejs v10, v12, v14.15.1 and v16, both x86 and x64 varieties - there is no difference in behavior.) I've tried uninstalling nodejs and re-installing multiple times. I've tried with Powershell and with the windows Command Prompt.

I had this problem intermittently about 6 months ago and previously just rebooting windows seemed to clear this up. I'm guessing that something has been corrupted in the OS somehow.

Tracing through nodejs through the nodejs debug inspect shows it hits this line and then just quits silently when stepping into this line of code:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e46c680bf2b211bbd52cf959ca17ee98c7f657f5/lib/internal/child_process.js#L390

```
const err = this._handle.spawn(options);
```

I don't see anything odd/wrong in the options object and I've tried with various different environment variable settings for PATH, etc.

**UPDATE:**
Looks like things work fine if windows is started in safe mode or started with early launch anti-malware protection disabled. Now, I'm suspecting something with anti-virus software is interfering here.

Comment: try adding event listeners to the child process such as `.on('error', err => {console.log('got error', err)}` to get more information

Comment: you got any solution for this? I'm also facing same issue, its not opening exe in production, it exists silently, no error's

Comment: See my answer below. This was due to Carbon Black antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some new anti-virus rules were blocking all processes attempting to spawn a new cmd.exe child process.